# Loading is slow when there are many items in select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using select2, but when using the list as ajax, the loading speed becomes too slow as the number of rows increases.

I don't know if it's slow because I'm using it incorrectly

```
$.ajax('/board/getAsClient', {
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('${_csrf.headerName}', '${_csrf.token}');
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#clientList").select2({
            data: result,
            theme: "bootstrap",
            width: '100%'
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        Swal.fire({
            text: "loading error",
            icon: warning
        });
    }
});
```

I didn't know when there were about 100 rows, but I found out when there were thousands of rows.